# How to select the correct html block in python requests response

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using python requests and beautiful soup, how can I select the correct html block if multiple blocks may be returned in the response (or delete what I don't want)?

```
url = my_url + "cgi/interesting.cgi"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
print (soup.prettify())
```

The first time this script is run against a target, the contents of r.text is:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <script language="Javascript">
   top.topFrame.document.location.href="../cgi/navigation_frame.cgi";
   nothing to see here
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
<!-- cgi_interesting -->
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="stuff"/>
  <link href="things"/>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <script language="Javascript">
  </script>
interesting content
</body>  
</html>
```

And the script returns (unintended):

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <script language="Javascript">
   top.topFrame.document.location.href="../cgi/navigation_frame.cgi";
   nothing to see here
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
<!-- cgi_interesting -->
```

If the script is called subsequently, the first block is absent and the interesting content is output; r.text looks like this:

```
<!-- cgi_interesting -->
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="stuff"/>
  <link href="things"/>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <script language="Javascript">
  </script>
interesting content
</body>  
</html>
```

And the script returns (as intended):

```
<!-- cgi_interesting -->
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="stuff"/>
  <link href="things"/>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <script language="Javascript">
  </script>
interesting content
</body>  
</html>
```

If the target hasn't been queried before, both blocks are present in `r.text`. It seems that beautifulsoup only handles the first block it finds.

I would like the code to work no matter whether the first block is present or not. How can I test `r.text` for multiple `html` blocks, select the appropriate one, and pass it to beautifulsoup?

I am currently investigating using `re.sub` to delete anything prior to `<!-- cgi_interesting -->` but is there a better way?

Comment: You say that you get the html blocks on different calls, then you say they are in the same `r.text`. So..., which?

Comment: @tdelaney post edited for clarity I hope

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar no sorry, it's on an internal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than keep each block of html I used `re.sub` to get rid of anything prior to the html comment since it wasn't needed. Successfully finished looping through over 60 sites.

```
url = my_url + "cgi/interesting.cgi"
r = requests.get(url)
result = re.sub("(?s).*?(<!-- cgi_interesting -->)","\\1", r.text, 1, flags=re.DOTALL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
print (soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 2):

That html is more invalid than beautifulsoup can deal with. Give a hand to whoever wrote such a buggy site! You could slice up the buffer at `</html>` boundaries and use soup multiple times:

```
url = my_url + "cgi/interesting.cgi"
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.content

html_blocks = []

# save declarations for all blocks
html_index = content.find(b'<html>')
if html_index >= 0:
    decl = content[:html_index]
    del content[:html_index]

    # find html extents
    while content:

        # find end tag
        extent = content.find(b'</html>')
        if extent >= 0:
            extent += len(b'</html>')
        else:
            # no end tag, hope BS figures it out
            extent = len(content)

        # put in list and delete from input
        html_blocks.append(delc + content[:extent]
        del content[:extent]

        # advance to next html tag
        html_index = content.find(b'<html>')
        if html_index == -1:
            html_index = len(content)
        del content[:html_index]


for block in html_blocks:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(block, "lxml")
    print (soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I was looking at using `re.sub` on the `<!-- cgi_interesting -->` line as then I don't have to choose which block to process. But I'm having issues with that. I can use your solution to do the same thing. PS. it's an appliance; buggy site runs on flaky tcp stack!

Comment: Runtime error at the first instance of `del content[:html_index]` "TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item deletion". I tried with r.text for a similar error. Sounds odd, have I done something wrong?

Comment: That was me not checking whether it works. Do `content = content[html_index:]` for an explicit copy.

Comment: A split should would too. `r.text.split("<!-- cgi_interesting -->")`.

Comment: The problem with trying to get them all into a single doc is that there are multiple head and body tags as well. Once you've built the two html documents, you can then select the `body` of the second and copy its child elements into the `body` of the first.